# Angular route redirect to backend and return http

Tags: node.js, angular

I have configured a proxy to backend API for my Angular like this

```html
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "router": {
      "localhost:4200" : "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:4200" : "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to add a href like this

```html
<a href="/api/json" color="warn">JSON</a>
```

That should hit `localhost:4200/api/json` and be redirected to `localhost:3000/api/json`, but it does not work.

Using the routing module there is no path `{ path: 'api', component: APIRedirectComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix'}` that can make an http call that will use the proxy configured.

I was thinking of creating a module that reads the location and then makes a http call, but then I realised that angular will generate a response with `text/html` and render the page.

How can I design a component that will return a `application/json` response from a call to the backend or simply proxy to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but you can remove the /* after /api

It'll do the redirection with everything after /api

If you don't want to have /api in your URL, you can remove it with a pathRewrite in your configuration

Comment: That redirect only works for calls with http.get(), but not for routing, as the angular route will try to find a path